# Java if Stuff in joptionpane

Tags: java, if-statement, random, joptionpane

After a long time i came back to java and i try to write(with my beginners knowledge) a short game about random numbers

The game should look like that:

1. A Text box appears which asks for the difficulty (Done)
2. A random number appears according to the difficulty (Stuck)
3. A Textbox says "You Won, roll Again?" or "You Lose, roll Again" in both cases a loop is needed that starts at 2. (no clue...)

I'm currently stuck at 2.

I can generate a random number but after I choose the difficulty nothing happens.

Here's the code :

```
package randomnumbergame;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RandomNumberGame { 

    static double n;
    static double e;
    static double h;
    static Component frame;            
    static String answer;

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        String[] options = new String[] {"Easy", "Normal", "Hard"};            
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "What Difficulty do you want ?", "Difficulty",                            
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);
        {
            if ("Hard".equals(answer)) {
                n = Math.random();        
                long n3 = Math.round(Math.random() * 99999);
                System.out.println(n3);                        
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, n3, "Your randomly generated Number is:", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } else if ("Normal".equals(answer)) {
                h = Math.random();   
                long n4 = Math.round(Math.random() * 9999);
                System.out.println(n4);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, n4, "Your randomly generated Number is:", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);                                       
            } else if ("Easy".equals(answer)) {                
                e = Math.random();
                long e4 = Math.round(Math.random() * 999);
                System.out.println(e4);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e4, "Your randomly generated Number is:", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what is wrong with it?
I looked through several Questions here, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: `Object answer = null; }` is closing the `main` method, the rest of the code won't be executed when you run it.

Comment: okay, when i delete it i get the message "non-static variable n cannot be referenced from a static context" the same with answer, frame, h and e

Comment: `main` is a static method, so all of your variables need to be static, i.e., `static double n;`

Comment: after adding static to all variables it is still not working. no errors nor output

Comment: you never set `answer` to a value.

Comment: i feel kinda stupid but ... how do i do that ? and thanks btw Jon for your help so far.

Comment: You should be able to do `String answer = (String) JOptionPane.showOptionDialog...`

Comment: @Jon Cast `int` to `String`? Good idea, I guess.

Comment: @Tom I was thinking of `showInputDialog(...)`. Here, I guess it would be `int idx = JOptionPane... ; String answer = options[idx];`

Comment: @Jon Yes, looks much better :).

Comment: `int index = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...`, see [the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) for the meaning of the return value

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the result from the `JOptionPane`...

```
int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...,
if (selection != -1) {
    answer = options[selection];
```

See the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) for more details about the meaning of the return value...